# How to add condition inside @object.map inside f.select in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, dictionary

I'm trying to do a select with all the countries in the world with the number of users inside () in the right part of the name. This is how my dropdown menu should look like:

--ALL-- (15)
Spain (2)
United States (10)
Slovakia (3)

So far I have all the countries and users listed like this in the select for all countries, but the problem comes with the --ALL-- option. The --All-- option value is "". It should count all the users in the world, but is counting all the users that have no country, with the value "" in the database.

This is the code how I show all the countries for each value of the select:

```
<%= f.label :country, "Country" %>
<% if @country_sel %>
  <%= f.select :country_sel, @country.map{ |p|    [p.country_name + ' ('+ User.where("cc_iso LIKE ?", p.cc_iso).count().to_s + ')', p.cc_iso] }, :selected => @country_sel %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.select :country_sel, @country.map{ |p| [p.country_name + ' ('+ User.where("cc_iso LIKE ?", p.cc_iso).count().to_s + ')', p.cc_iso] } %>
<% end %>
```

An this is the code I'm trying to write in order to have all the countries in the world listed in the right of the --ALL-- option.

```
<% if @country_sel %>
    <%= f.select :country_sel, @country.map{ |p| [p.country_name + ' ('+ User.where("cc_iso LIKE ?", p.cc_iso).count().to_s + ')', p.cc_iso] }, :selected => @country_sel %>
  <% else %><%= f.select :country_sel, @country.map{ |p| [p.country_name + ' ('+ %>
        <% if p.country_name == "" %><%= User.all.count().to_s + ')', p.cc_iso] } %><%else %><%= User.where("cc_iso LIKE ?", p.cc_iso).count().to_s + ')', p.cc_iso] } %> 
        <%end%> 
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know how to write if condition inside a map inside a `f.select`.
I don't know if I am going the right way :)

May you please help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: if `@country` is an object, can't you call `@country.users.count` ?

Comment: Hello Mohammad, of course i can do it that way too. The problem is.. where do i put it inside the map? Is needed only for the ALL option.

Comment: Set up your association properly like @MohammadAbuShady said and don't write everything inside your select. Make a helper method, write code inside it and call that helper method in your select

Comment: why do you even need map, just do `[@country.name + @country.users.count.to_s, @country.cc_iso]`, also i think that whole if condition is a waste, rails should be smart enough to understand if `@country_sel` is `nil`

Comment: But i dont know how to put it later inside the map...may you please writte the code here so i can see? The thing is that i need to put a filter inside the map and when the p.countryname == "" then it has to do @country.users.count and User.where("cc_iso LIKE ?", p.cc_iso).count().to_s for the rest of countries of the  dropdown menu

Comment: I need the map because @country is an array of objets and i need to list all the countries in the select, no just the all option. I dont know if i understand you very good. May you please writte me all code? I would like to add an image, but still i can't... thank you

Comment: could you include more of the view's code, the part before where you're looping through the countries.

Comment: Hello Mohammad, you were right, that condition was a waste :) Im quite new with programming

Comment: It is a partial: <%= form_for(:menu, :url => {:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index'}, :html => {:id => 'menu'}) do |f| %>
<%= render partial: "menu.html.erb", locals: { :f => f } %>
<% end %>.   You can see the live example here: http://putitos-130711.euw1.nitrousbox.com:4000/ Countries with some cities loaded working are Spain and Andorra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your countries are in an array, first off you better do the total calculation in the controller

```
@total_users = @countries.inject{|total,country| total+= country.users.count}
```

Or if you can do it from the model directly that would be nice too, like `User.count` or something

Then in the view

```
f.select :country_sel, @countries.collect{|country| ["#{country.name} (#{country.users.count.to_s})", country.id] }, selected: @country_sel, include_blank: "All (#{total_users})"
```

Comment: This looks definitely much better that what i have now with map. And that include_blank tag i didn't know about its existance is probably the key of all my headaches. I will try it and let you know.  Also Jay is right. Thank you all

Comment: This last method country.users would obligate me to create an aditional table for country/users and relate them. My database now is that i store everything in users table  included countries and cities. And i have one separate table for countries as source for the select. And finally it would have to count as well separately in database.. But i will create an scope for the query in the model and not counting users in the view, but in the controller. Include it in one hash and list it in the view. Thank you very much :)

Comment: could you explain the table structure more, what are the table names and how you link objects together

Comment: I have table users with columns "age, genre, mail,... country, city". I have the table countries with columns "cc_iso, country name". Both of them are independent. The table countries is the source to serve the data to the select. When someone makes a search in the select, it goes the query to users table and pick the users that their cc_iso for the country match with the selected

Comment: 2 questions, is `user.country (in db)` a string or an integer?, does country table have an id?

Comment: user.country is a string. Country table doesn't have id, i didnt create a migration for it. I took all the data from here http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free. There you can see the country table structure. With your method i would have to create a table in the middle with country_name/user.id and a one to many association...

Comment: well for me i would add an id to the countries table, and create a country_id field in the user, then write a loop to populate the country_id field in the users, if you don't have a country model then it's better to create one, just to stick to the rails conventions.

Comment: Yes i have a country model :) This is how i list all the countries for the select. Yes probably is the best way to go. I dont need to create a loop, im in development i only have 4 users, i can do it manually. But i'm a bit lazy ass and i hate to modify databases and migrations XD. But is true that it can save me headaches in the future. I will do it that way, thank you very much Mohammad :)

Comment: Hello mohammad, i created a rich many to many relationship. I did all like you told me, but now i have one issue. How can i apply a filter to search in a many to many relationship? I have table users with columns, table countries with columns and in the middle the table country_relationships with columns id, user_id, country_id and city. I have a search form and i need to find the user with the country_id :23 for example. But using the User model. how can i do it? User.where(country_id: "23") desnt work.

Comment: don't try to use the `country_id` directly, instead do something like `User.joins(:countries).where(countries: {id: 23})`

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but the short answer is, "don't". Your view shouldn't be this smart. Create your list of countries and counts in your controller and pass them to the view. Your `f.select` then becomes just a matter of combining the country name (include the meta "--ALL--" country) with the number of users.

In addition to simplifying your view, it opens up opportunities to make your code much more efficient by using [`group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) rather than individual queries for each country.